# Stop users logging in to the sitecore CMS with the same account in different browsers

Tags: security

A client has requested that they would like to stop users being able to log into sitecore with the same account in different browsers or machines etc.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: One idea would be to write a logging in process to check if an existing session matches the new user. Then you can boot the user out.